# Vue JS how to change value of varaible on chosen select's option

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js

I got 3 options in select and want to textbox appear when third is chosen, how to do this? i got this so far for this moemnt but it doesnt work.

```
<select asp-for="UploadOption" name="UploadOption">
  <option value="1" selected="selected" name="img">PNG/JPG/WEBP image</option>
  <option value="2" name="video">GIF/APNG/WEBM video</option>
  <option v-on:change="streamable = true" value="3" name="streamable">Streamable</option>
</select>
<input v-if="streamable" type="url" placeholder="https://streamable.com/dxe6b" />
<label v-else>Choose file type you'd like to upload</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `v-model` for your select, and show/hide the input based on when the model is the value you want.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    uploadOption: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select name="UploadOption" v-model="uploadOption">
    <option value="1">PNG/JPG/WEBP image</option>
    <option value="2">GIF/APNG/WEBM video</option>
    <option value="3">Streamable</option>
  </select>
  <input v-if="uploadOption == 3" type="url" placeholder="https://streamable.com/dxe6b" />
  <label v-else>Choose file type you'd like to upload</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I believe that's the way as well!

Comment: No, no, I'm just learning from the masters :D We learn a lot from the interactions here, I think!

Comment: Thanks, I see that it works on this sandbox, but it doesn't work on my site :\ but if I type in console app.upload.. = 3 textbox appears, but still not with selection.

Comment: @kubawich Without seeing your code, that sounds like the `v-model` is not rendered properly (note the `v-model` attribute added to the select).

Comment: Here's whole site's code https://github.com/kubawich/nsfwpics/blob/master/Pages/Add.cshtml

Comment: Don't mind comments i just made commit without it since it doesn't work, but it wasn't commented when i was testing it.

Comment: @kubawich I don't see anything obviously wrong with that template.

Comment: Me neither, but after deploy it doesn't work with console help